# Cancelling an AngularJS ng-click event from a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I've written a directive that should allow text to be selectable when inside on an element with an `ng-click` on it. When the mouse is pressed and then moved past a threshold the click event is cancelled.

Right now this only **partially** works and I can't figure out why.  When the text is contained within another child element it works.  Otherwise, it doesn't.

```html
<tr>
  <td selectable-text ng-click="doThing()">
    When this text is selected the click event fires regardless
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td selectable-text ng-click="doThing()">
    <strong>When this text is selected, the click does not fire (as expected!)</strong>
  </td>
</tr>
```

#### DEMO: http://codepen.io/chrismbarr/pen/wgLJBx

```ts
app.directive("selectableText", () => {
  const mouseMoveThreshold = 5; //in pixels

  const linkFn = (_$scope: angular.IScope, $element: angular.IRootElementService): void => {
    let killClick = false;

    $element.on("mousedown", (downEvent: JQueryMouseEventObject) => {
      //reset this with each click
      killClick = false;

      //When the mouse button is pressed, start watching the mouse movements and record the differences
      const diffs = { x: 0, y: 0 };
      $element.on("mousemove", (moveEvent: JQueryMouseEventObject) => {
        diffs.x = Math.abs(moveEvent.clientX - downEvent.clientX);
        diffs.y = Math.abs(moveEvent.clientY - downEvent.clientY);
        console.info(diffs);
        if (diffs.x >= mouseMoveThreshold || diffs.y >= mouseMoveThreshold) {
          //If the mouse have moved more than the threshold in any direction, cancel the default click event behavior
          killClick = true;
        }
      });
    });

    $element[0].addEventListener('click', (evt: MouseEvent) => {
      //When the mouse button is released, kill the move event no matter what
      $element.off("mousemove");
      if (killClick) {
        console.info("Should have killed click event")
        //if set, stop the default click event from happening
        //I've tried all of these...
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();
        evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
      }
    }, true);
  };

  return {
    link: linkFn,
    restrict: 'A'
  };
});
```

Comment: As for me it works same. But this actually doesnt matter -- this idea in general seems wrong, there are a lot of ways to select - using shift, double click, (smth else?). Also I didnt face such behavior in web, so it is not common -- usually if mouse is "pointer" u may click OR it looks like select and u can select -- combining these will just confuse user.

Comment: The goal is just to allow people to select text if they want to do so, just something "extra".  It's not a primary feature.  I'm trying to reduce confusion by allowing the text to be selectable instead of the click event firing when they attempt this.  However... yes my demo does seem to be working correctly for me as well... so I'm not entirely sure why that code isn't working in my app right now.  Very strange!